# Server host key changing frequently

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys, man-in-the-middle, fingerprint

Im trying to connect to my ubuntu server via ssh from Windows. Unlike my another ubuntu server from same dedicated server hosting, the server host key changing frequently.
I get `WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!` and fingerprint `SHA256:...6MyI`.

with this key and fingerprint whenever i enter my password the ssh give me error: `Permission denied, please try again.` and  `Permission denied (publickey,password).`

i remove the ed25519 key from `.ssh/known_hosts` every time this key store to monitor the key changes. after few minuets of try, this key and fingerprint changes and when i enter same password i can connect to server. but after few minuets(not same every time) i disconnect from server by `connection reset by peer`. and when i want to connect again the key is changed back to wrong one and showing fingerprint `SHA256:...6MyI`.

i tried reboot, i asked hosting provider to reset the server (i'm not sure what they done because the root password didn't change) but nothing changed.
and also i tried `rm -v /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*` -> `dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server` -> `systemctl restart ssh` and `ssh-keygen -A` to reset host key from server but this only change the working key that let me connect by password, not affect on wrong key.

is this done by any script or automation? how can i stop this?

Comment: That pattern suggests you are connecting to more than one backend server. For example, two DNS entries for the same domain and the two servers pointed to do not have the same SSH host keys. Or duplicate IP addresses (same IP assigned to more than one server).

Comment: @brian thanks for you reply! i used ```arping``` and noticed this is duplicate IP addresses issue. only thing can i do is ask hosting provider to fix it, right?

Comment: Correct. Would need to provide what you have found to your provider to investigate.

Comment: Thank you, yo can post it as an answer and i will accept it